lsb_release.py missing from lsb-release package on Noble
On Focal, the lsb-release package included the file /usr/share/pyshared/lsb_release.py which is then linked from /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/lsb_release.py. However these are not included in the lsb-release package on Noble.
Is there a replacement for this functionality from Python ? I'm really interested in the release information from lsb_release.get_os_release() so I'm not sure if another package exposes this.
Thanks for your time.

I suspect the omission is related to the migration of the source package for lsb-release from lsb to lsb-release-minimal. To identify possible replacements, we can ask aptitude to look for packages with python3 in their names that also depend on lsb-release:
$ aptitude search '?and(~npython3)?depends(lsb-release)'
i A python3-commandnotfound                                                       - Python 3 bindings for command-not-found.                                                
i A python3-distro                                                                - Linux OS platform information API                                                       
i A python3-distupgrade                                                           - manage release upgrades                                                                 
p   python3-kerberos                                                              - GSSAPI interface module - Python 3.x                                                    
i A python3-software-properties                                                   - manage the repositories that you install software from

So a likely candidate is the distro module from python3-distro:
On 22.04:
$ dpkg-query -W -f '${source:Package}\n' lsb-release
lsb

$ python3 -c 'import lsb_release; print(lsb_release.get_os_release())'
{'DESCRIPTION': 'Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS', 'RELEASE': '22.04', 'CODENAME': 'jammy', 'ID': 'Ubuntu'}

On 24.04:
$ dpkg-query -W -f '${source:Package}\n' lsb-release
lsb-release-minimal

$ python3 -c 'import distro; print(distro.lsb_release_info())'
{'distributor_id': 'Ubuntu', 'description': 'Ubuntu 24.04 LTS', 'release': '24.04', 'codename': 'noble'}

